# Google maps : Possible to add multiple businesses with co-ords not postcode?

Tags: google-maps

We're keen to get our database of businesses onto googlemaps' own database by uploading a data file here : http://www.google.com/local/add/analyticsSplashPage?hl=en-gb&gl=gb

our address data is in co-ords format but it looks like it only works with a postcode - is there a method for using co-ordinates instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing latitude/longitude values, you can convert them into postal codes (reverse geocoding).

There's an example in Google maps docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#ReverseGeocoding